# find all subdomains in a string using php

Tags: php, regex

hello here is my html :

```
<div>
hello.domain.com
holla.domain.com
stack.domain.com
overflow.domain.com </div>
```

I want to return an array with : `hello, holla, stack,overflow`

then I have this `https://hello.domain.com/c/mark?lang=fr`
I want to return the value : `mark`
I know it should be done with regular expressions. As long as I know how to do it regular expression or not it will be good. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Part 1: Subdomains

```
$regex = '~\w+(?=\.domain\.com)~i';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the matches in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/5).

**Match Array:**

```
[0] => hello
[1] => holla
[2] => stack
[3] => overflow
```

**Explanation**

- The `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive
- `\w+` matches letters, digits or underscores (our match)
- The lookahead `(?=\.domain\.com)` asserts that it is followed by `.domain.com`

### Part 2: Substring

```
$regex = '~https://hello\.domain\.com/c/\K[^\s#?]+(?=\?)~';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring, $m)) {
    $thematch = $m[0];
    } 
else { // no match...
     }
```

See the match in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/6).

**Explanation**

- `https://hello\.domain\.com/c/` matches `https://hello.domain.com/c/`
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `[^\s#?]+` matches any chars that are not a white-space char, `?` or `#` url fragment marker
- The lookahead `(?=\?)` asserts that it is followed by a `?`

Comment: FYI: added regex demo for each pattern + explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure where you are trying to take this.

```
$input = 'somthing.domain.com';

$string = trim($input, '.domain.com');
```

may help you.

Comment: The second paramater of [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is `string $character_mask`. This imho just trims any `.acdiomn` and stops at the `g`, because it's not in the charlist. [See example](http://ideone.com/OMkrKl).

Answer (score 0):

About the second part of your question, you can use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
$yourURL = 'https://hello.domain.com/c/mark?lang=fr';

$result = end(explode('/', parse_url($yourURL, PHP_URL_PATH)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question (extract part of a URL) others have answered with a highly specific regex solution. More generally what you are trying to do is parse a URL for which there already exists the [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function. You will find the following more flexible and applicable to other URLs:

```
php > $url = 'https://hello.domain.com/c/mark?lang=fr';
php > $urlpath = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
php > print $urlpath ."\n";
/c/mark
php > print basename($urlpath) . "\n";
mark
php > $url = 'ftp://some.where.com.au/abcd/efg/wow?lang=id&q=blah';
php > print basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)) . "\n";
```

This assumes that you are after the last part of the URL path, but you could use `explode("/", $urlpath)` to access other components in the path.